# Make Jahia User non-visible to the admin of another virtual site

Tags: java, content-management-system, user-management

We have a requirement that every virtual site should have its set of users which will not be visible to the admins of another virtual site.

I know that documentation http://www.jahia.com/files/live/sites/jahiacom/files/documentation/6.61/en/Jahia6.61_AdminGuide.pdf says that all the virtual sites share the same users.

So does it mean that it's not possible to avoid this kind of security issues or there are some workarounds that I'm not aware of?

Any comments/suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was answered in the Jahia Forum here :

http://www.jahia.com/home/download/forum/general/jahia-in-english/make-jahia-user-non-visible-to-t.html

Basically it is not possible yet, but it may be added in a future version. Otherwise you still have the possibility to download the source and perform modifications, but these will not be trivial as it involves modifying some GWT interfaces and maintain your own fork of these.